# Routing for multiple subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, subdomain

I'm trying to specify routes (specifically, the `root` route), dependent on what the current subdomain. I want to route to `controller#action1` if the subdomain is `subdomain`; to `controller#action2` if the subdomain is present but *not* `subdomain` or `www`; and to `controller#action3` if the subdomain is `www` or not given.

I tried the following:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  scope :constraints => { :subdomain => "subdomain" } do
    match "/" => "controller#action1"
  end

  scope :constraints => lambda {|req| req.subdomain.present? && !%w(subdomain www).include?(req.subdomain) } do
    match "/" => "controller#action2"  
  end

  root :to => "controller#action3"
end
```

Browsing to `subdomain.myapp.com` and `other.myapp.com` both work as expected (going to `action1` and `action2`, respectively). However, when I try `myapp.com` or `www.myapp.com`, I get:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/"
```

When I run `rake routes`, I see

```
      / {:subdomain=>"subdomain", :controller=>"controller", :action=>"action1"}
      / {:controller=>"controller", :action=>"action2"}
root  / {:controller=>"controller", :action=>"action3"}
```

So I guess (speculating) that because there are two routes for `/` that don't specify a subdomain, my fallback route tries to match the second but then doesn't meet the constraints and fails? What can I do to get this working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been a bug in the routing-filter gem, and seems to be fixed as of more recent versions of the gem and the routing changes in Rails 3.2.